# Permissions removed while upgrading from AEM6.0 to AEM6.1

Tags: aem, aem-6

We recently upgraded from AEM6.0 to AEM6.1 and noticed that there were users and groups which lost their permissions to specific paths as part of the upgrade.
/content/abc/xyz/products/[pages1...20]
Now when i try to give read permissions manually on products node..it is not giving permissions on child nodes.

What is the best way to restore the permissions that were active in AEM6.0?

Answer (score 2):

If you still have AEM6.0 backup somehow, you can create a package of rep:policy nodes with [ACS Commons ACL Packager](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/acl-packager.html) and move them to AEM 6.1